# How do I nest cdn loading of jquery and jquery-ui in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bookmarklet

I found examples of linking and loading jquery in bookmarklets but couldn't find a case where both jquery and jquery-ui were both loaded.

- [jQuery Bookmarklet Generator](http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/)
- [better stronger safer jqueryify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet/)

Here's the gist I'm working on:
[link text](https://gist.github.com/765720)
update the following gist is functional now.

```
<a href='javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,z,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){z=a.createElement("script");z.type="text/javascript";z.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js";z.onload=z.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}}})(window,document,"1.4.4",function($,L){/*ENTER JQUERY-UI CODE HERE*/});'>CC</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following bookmarklet to work:

```
    javascript:
(function(){
  var s1=window.document.createElement('script');
  s1.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js');
  window.document.body.appendChild(s1);
  var s2=window.document.createElement('script');
  s2.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js');
  window.document.body.appendChild(s2);
  s1.onload=s1.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(!this.readyState||this.readyState=='loaded'||this.readyState=='complete'){
      s2.onload=s2.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(!this.readyState||this.readyState=='loaded'||this.readyState=='complete'){
          $('div').draggable();
          $('div').resizable();
          $('div').css({'border-style':'dashed','border-width':'3px','border-color':'black','background':'#00ccFF'});
        }
      }
      ;
    }
  }
  ;
}
)();
```

Here's the same bookmarklet compressed with white spaces purged and ready for use:

```
javascript:(function(){var s1=window.document.createElement('script');s1.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js');window.document.body.appendChild(s1);var s2=window.document.createElement('script');s2.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js');window.document.body.appendChild(s2);s1.onload=s1.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!this.readyState||this.readyState=='loaded'||this.readyState=='complete'){s2.onload=s2.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!this.readyState||this.readyState=='loaded'||this.readyState=='complete'){$('div').draggable();$('div').resizable();$('div').css({'border-style':'dashed','border-width':'3px','border-color':'black','background':'#00ccFF'});}};}};})();
```

References:

- I found the following site very helpful for improving the readability and writing bookmarklets: [subsimple.com](http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm)
- Also for testing [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/victusfate/2wncB/) proved very helpful while on the go